# Create new columns by applying a function on selected rows pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, poisson

I would like to use the following function on a large dataset, 300000 rows with 1500 unique ID. And create two new columns as in below. The function below works when applied to the data frame as a whole (len(df1)). But I want to apply it based on length of each unique ID.

```
d = {'ID':['a12', 'a12','a12','b33','b33','b33','v55','v55','v55','v55'], 'Exp_A':[2.2,2.2,2.2,3.1,3.1,3.1,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5], 
     'Exp_B':[2.4,2.4,2.4,1.2,1.2,1.2,1.5,1.5,1.5,1.5], 
     'A':[0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1], 'B':[0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

def adj_Apois(row):
    i = row.name 
    if row.A == 1:
        return poisson.pmf(row.A, row.Exp_A*(i+1)/len(df1)) * row.Exp_A   
    else:
        return poisson.pmf(row.A, row.Exp_A*(i+1)/len(df1)) * row.Exp_A

def adj_Bpois(row):
    i = row.name 
    if row.B == 1:
        return poisson.pmf(row.B, row.Exp_B*(i+1)/len(df1)) * row.Exp_B
    else:
        return poisson.pmf(row.B, row.Exp_B*(i+1)/len(df1)) * row.Exp_B


df1['New1'] = df1.apply(adj_Apois, axis=1)
df1['New2'] = df1.apply(adj_Bpois, axis=1)
```

**Desired out come**

replacing df1 above with length of unique ID yield the following

```
    A   B   Exp_A   Exp_B   ID  new1    new2
0   0   0   2.2      2.4    a12 1.05667 1.07839
1   0   0   2.2      2.4    a12 0.50752 0.48455
2   0   1   2.2      2.4    a12 0.24377 0.86271
3   1   0   3.1      1.2    b33 1.13981 0.80438
4   0   1   3.1      1.2    b33 0.39248 0.43136
5   1   0   3.1      1.2    b33 0.43292 0.36143
6   0   1   1.5      1.5    v55 1.03093 0.3866
7   1   0   1.5      1.5    v55 0.53141 0.70855
8   0   1   1.5      1.5    v55 0.48698 0.54785
9   1   0   1.5      1.5    v55 0.50204 0.33469
```

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: If the outcome of using the function is correct, then what is your question?

Comment: Do you mean to have the same code for the if and else?

Comment: @G.Anderson, I’m sorry for not making the question clear please see the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, just use [`poisson.pmf`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.poisson.html) directly

```
from spicy.stats import poisson

df1['New2a'] =  poisson.pmf(df1.B, df1.Exp_B*(df1.index+1)/len(df1)) * df1.Exp_B
df1['New1a'] =  poisson.pmf(df1.A, df1.Exp_A*(df1.index+1)/len(df1)) * df1.Exp_A
```

Yields same results

```
>>> df1['New1a'].eq(df1['New1']).all()
True
```

---

To group:

```
>>> df1.groupby('ID').apply(lambda s: poisson.pmf(s.B, s.Exp_B*(s.index+1)/len(s)) * s.Exp_B).reset_index()
```

Comment: how about if the length inside the Poisson function is length of the unique ID associated with Exp_A or Exp_B?

Comment: @MatN Not sure I understand, but you can just `groupby`. Check edited

Comment: groupby doesn't give the same output as in above.

Comment: @MatN I don't understand how you get to this result. What do you mean `length of the unique ID`? If it is `3` for `a12` , `3` for `b33` and `4` for `v55`, the code I posted should be ok.

Comment: Yes, thats correct. Except each ID should be reindexed so 'index' inside the apply function will be 0,1,2 for a12, 0,1,2 for b33 and 0,1,2,3 for v55.

Comment: s.Exp_B.index solve it. Thank you for your help Rafael.

Comment: @MatN So glad you could work it out and that I could help a little ! happy coding !